# Delete files in the drop location

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-deployment

I am trying to delete the folder with name "repro" and its contents in my build drop location. I have configured my delete files steps as below

Source Folder: $(BuildDropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\CTrest\lime

Contents:

**/repro/*

[image]

repro folder resides here 
$(BuildDropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\CTrest\lime\version\package\code**repro**..

Is there something that I am missing here?

Comment: If you want to delete the folder with name 'repro', you should use `**/repro*` as @Shamrai Aleksander pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the doc for the command: [Delete Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/delete-files?view=azure-devops). Examples of contents:

> `**/temp/*` deletes all files in any sub-folder named temp.
>
> `**/temp*` deletes any file or folder with a name that begins with temp.

I think, `**/repro*` will be more suitable in your case.